# Using Rust to call Geth's RPC interface

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, rust

Given the code below, geth returns:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1","error":{"code":-32602,"message":
"json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []interface {}"}}
```

The code connects to geth, but I am obviously sending the wrong data for `params`. Geth wants `[]` and not an `object`. If I change the code to send a `string` that looks like `[]`, geth still complains.

Question: how do I send a `[]` to geth?

```
#[macro_use] extern crate hyper;
extern crate rustc_serialize;
extern crate url;

use std::io::Read;
use hyper::{Client};
use hyper::header::{Headers, ContentType};
use rustc_serialize::{Encodable, json};
use rustc_serialize::json::Object;

fn post_json<T>(url: &str, payload: &T) -> hyper::Result<String>
    where T: Encodable {
    let client = Client::new();
    let body = json::encode(payload).unwrap();
    let mut response = try!(client.post(url).header(ContentType::json()).body(&body[..]).send());
    let mut buf = String::new();
    try!(response.read_to_string(&mut buf));
    Ok(buf)
}
#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct Param {
    num: String,
    detail: bool,
}
#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct RpcRequest {
    jsonrpc: String,
    method: String,
    params: Param,
    id: String,
}
fn main() {
    let request = RpcRequest {
        jsonrpc: "2.0".to_owned(),
        method: "eth_getBlockByNumber".to_owned(),
        params: Param { num: "1".to_owned(), detail: true },
        id: "1".to_owned(),
    };
    println!("{}", post_json("http://localhost:8545", &request).unwrap());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `params` field in JSON-RPC needs to be an array, while you are passing a single serialized `Param` struct. To create a dynamic array containing different JSON-primitive values you can use a `Vec<Json>` (where `Json` is a `rustc_serialize::json::Json` enum):

```
use rustc_serialize::json::Json;

// ...

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct RpcRequest {
    jsonrpc: String,
    method: String,
    params: Vec<Json>,
    id: String,
}
```

And then:

```
let request = RpcRequest {
    jsonrpc: "2.0".into(),
    method: "eth_getBlockByNumber".into(),
    params: vec![Json::String("1".into()), Json::Boolean(true)],
    id: "1".into(),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [rust-web3](https://github.com/tomusdrw/rust-web3) library. It allows you to content to either geth or parity clients through http and ipc. Using the rpc is as simple as

```
extern crate web3;

use web3::futures::Future;

fn main() {
  let web3 = web3::Web3::new(web3::transports::Http::new("http://localhost:8545").unwrap());
  let accounts = web3.eth().accounts().wait().unwrap();

  println!("Accounts: {:?}", accounts);
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I've been watching your github. Is the Rust web3 stuff released?

Comment: yes, we've just released 0.0.5 https://crates.io/crates/web3